# How can I get a dependency extension from an DefaultExternalModuleDependency in gradle?

Tags: gradle, dependencies

I'm trying to get all the dependencies I've configured in my build in order to solve the problem explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24743562/gradle-not-including-dependencies-in-published-pom-xml). My problem is that I have some dependency that have more than one artifact (for example a .zip and a .jar).
When I use configurations.compile.allDependencies.each I obtain an object of type DefaultExternalModuleDependency. From this object I can easily get groupId, version and artifact id but it seems not possible to get the type (the extension) that I've defined in the dependencies closure with @zip

How can I get it?

**UPDATE:**

This is what I'm doing:

```
dependencies {
    publish 'myorg:myart:1.9.4'
}
...
pom.withXml {
                def dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')
                configurations.publish.allDependencies.each{
                    ["zip","txt"].each { type ->
                        def dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', it.group)
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', it.name)
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('version', it.version)
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('type', type)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

By now, having always a .zip and a .txt file stored as artifact I resolved with an ["zip","txt"].each closure, but it remains a simplified way.

Thanks,
Michele.

Comment: Could you please show what you've tried? Sample `build.gradle` e.g.

Comment: I've updated the description