# Gradle maven-publish plugin produces pom with no dependencies

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, maven-publish

I have a project which has a `SharedCode` (Java) module and secondly an `Android` (Android library) module which depends on the `SharedCode` module. I've previously been using the `maven` plugin in my `build.gradle` files and I've been using the `uploadArchives` task of that plugin to publish the artifacts from my two modules. This has worked and produced pom files which reflect the dependencies in my `build.gradle` files.

I thought I'd replace the old `maven` plugin with the new `maven-publish` plugin. However, I see that the pom files produced by the `maven-publish` plugin contain no dependencies. Is this by design, is this a bug in the plugin or am I using the plugin incorrectly?

The `build.gradle` file in my `SharedCode` module is as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

group = "${projectGroupId}"
version = "${projectVersionName}"

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
}

publishing {
    publications {
        SharedCode(MavenPublication) {
            groupId "${projectGroupId}"
            artifactId 'SharedCode'
            version "${projectVersionName}"
            artifact("$buildDir/libs/SharedCode-${projectVersionName}.jar")
        }
    }
}
```

The `build.gradle` file in my `Android` module is as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

group = "${projectGroupId}"
version = "${projectVersionName}"

android {
    // android stuff here...
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':SharedCode')
}

publishing {
    publications {
        Android(MavenPublication) {
            groupId "${projectGroupId}"
            artifactId 'Android'
            version "${projectVersionName}"
            artifact "$buildDir/outputs/aar/Android-release.aar"
        }
    }
}
```

The pom file created from the `SharedCode` module is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
        http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
        xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.sdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>SharedCode</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.2</version>

</project>
```

The pom file created from the `Android` module is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
        http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
        xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.sdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>Android</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.2</version>
    <packaging>aar</packaging>

</project>
```

Note the absence of the dependencies in the pom files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `from components.java` instead of the `artifact...` line in your `publications` section for the java project. That should produce the dependencies in the pom automatically.

The android project isn't recognized as a standard java project, which makes it a bit trickier. You can create your own dependencies section using `pom.withXml {}` and then iterating through your dependency list. Alternatively, there is [this gradle plugin](https://github.com/dcendents/android-maven-gradle-plugin) that does it for yout.

Comment: Awesome! Replacing the `artifact...` line for `from components.java` in the `SharedCode` module fixes the problem for the `SharedCode` module. Just need to find a solution now for the `Android` module. Will follow your leads to see if that leads to a solution. Will get back to you.

Comment: I had the exact same problem and describe a solution in this blogpost: http://jeroenmols.com/blog/2015/08/13/artifactory2/ (see dependencies section)

Comment: Managed to solve the Android dependencies issue by adding `pom.withXml {}` to my `build.gradle`. This answer was a big help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24764713/1071320

Comment: Or try this [plugin](https://github.com/wupdigital/android-maven-publish) and use components.android

Comment: Thanks for the link bvarga. Does that plugin take care of adding dependency exclusions in the generated pom file?

Comment: bvarga, I just tried it and yes it does! Thanks for bringing this plugin to my attention. It works like a charm!

Comment: **Update:** The [digital.wup.android-maven-publish](https://github.com/wupdigital/android-maven-publish) Gradle plugin has been deprecated since the [maven-publish](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html) Gradle plugin is now supported by the Android Gradle plugin. See [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/maven-publish-plugin) for a short guide on how to use the `maven-publish` to publish an Android application or Android library.