# How to upload multiple artifacts / jars to maven repository / Artifactory using Gradle script with different custom pom files

Tags: maven, gradle, build.gradle, pom.xml, artifactory

I have a gradle script which uploads multiple jars to maven repo (Artifactory)

but the pom files generated with it are standard one and doesn't contain any dependency information

I am able to modify the script to upload a single jar with custom pom file by following below article
[Gradle not including dependencies in published pom.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24743562/gradle-not-including-dependencies-in-published-pom-xml)
(UploadWithPom.gradle attached)

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'java'


dependencies {
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.13.3"
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.13.3"
}

publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "<Artifactory url>"
            credentials {
                username = '<username>'
                password = '<pwd>'
        }
        }
    }

    publications {
        jar1(MavenPublication) {
            groupId 'my.group.id'
            artifactId 'localJar1'
            version '1.0.0'
            artifact ("localJar1.jar")
            pom.withXml 
            {
                    def dependencies  = asNode().appendNode("dependencies")
                    configurations.compile.allDependencies.each {  dep ->
                        def depNode  = dependencies.appendNode("dependency")
                        depNode.appendNode("groupId", dep.group)
                        depNode.appendNode("artifactId", dep.name)
                        depNode.appendNode("version", dep.version)
                        depNode.appendNode("scope","compile")
                    }
                }
           }
            
    }
    
}
```

Iam able to upload multiple jars separately (MultipleJarUpload.gradle) but it generated standard pom file content as below

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'java'


publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "<Artifactory url>"
            credentials {
                username = '<username>'
                password = '<pwd>'
        }
        }
    }

    publications {
        jar1(MavenPublication) {
            groupId 'my.group.id'
            artifactId 'localJar1'
            version '1.0.0'
            artifact ("localJar1.jar")
           }
        jar2(MavenPublication) {
            groupId 'my.group.id'
            artifactId 'localJar12'
            version '1.0.0'
            artifact ("localJar2.jar")
           }
            
    }
    
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>my.group.id</groupId>
  <artifactId>localJar1</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
</project>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>my.group.id</groupId>
  <artifactId>localJar2</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
</project>
```

I need to have the required pom files generated for all the jars with same build.gradle script

**EDIT - 1**
this gradle script is not part of any project, I am using it to upload few jars to Artifactory from linux terminal or from jenkins.
My requirement is to upload jar1 with dependency A and B, and to upload jar2 with dependency C and D from same build.gradle script.

```
// set java home and path
// set gradle home and path
gradle -b build.gradle publish
```

I have added all the dependencies in dependencies section as shown below

```
dependencies {
    // these are required for jar1
    compile "org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:3.3.1-test3"
    compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.36"
    
    // there are required for jar 2 
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.13.3"
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.13.3"
 }
```

when I run the script, it uploads both the jars with all the dependencies in the pom file generated, is there a way to specify / filter dependencies for different jars.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [Java Library](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html) plugin instead of the Java plugin. It will publish the dependencies of the library.

Comment: Hi Cisco, I have edited the question and added more details, can you please have a look again, thanks.